# Java Reference Object Duplicating

Tags: java, object, linked-list

Ok, here is the code I written

```
 public void Print( Object obj ){
    System.out.println( obj.toString() );
}

public Main() {

    LinkedList<Integer> link = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    LinkedList<Integer> temp = link;

    link.push(1);
    link.push(2);
    temp.push(10);

    while( link.isEmpty() == false ){
        Print( link.getLast() );
        link.removeLast();
    }
}
```

I guess it supposed to print 1 & 2 because I am pushing 10 into the temp variable, not link. But it's printing 1 2 10.

What's actually happening here? Can anyone explain this to me?

Thanks.

Comment: Both `temp` and `link` are pointing to the same reference. So anything you do to either object will effect the reference to each object, which is shared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand what Java references are.  They point to objects that live on the heap.

```
LinkedList<Integer> link = new LinkedList<Integer>();
LinkedList<Integer> temp = link;
```

When you set the `temp` equal to `link` you are equating *references*.  Both point to the same object on the heap.  If you modify the object using either reference, the other one sees it as well.

If you want temp to be independent of link, then do this:

```
List<Integer> link = new LinkedList<Integer>();
List<Integer> temp = new LinkedList<Integer>(link);
```

Now when you add 10 to `temp` only its object on the heap will see the change.

Answer (score 3):

Java only has primitive and reference variable types. Your variables

```
LinkedList<Integer> link = new LinkedList<Integer>(); // reference to a list
LinkedList<Integer> temp = link; // another reference to the same list.
```

You only created one `new` LinkedList, so whether you use one reference or the other you still have one list.